# Swift/iOS FirebaseGoogleSignIn OAuth client ID not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

Working with Swift/iOS and FirebsaeAuthUI and FirebaseGoogleAuthUI.
Code & setup are identical to approach I'd used in prior apps. I now have an M1 Mac running BigSur, and when I execute the code, it runs, but clicking the "Sign in With Google" default from FirebaseAuthUI returns an error:
Thread 1: "OAuth client ID not found. Please make sure Google Sign-In is enabled in the Firebase console. You may have to download a new GoogleService-Info.plist file after enabling Google Sign-In."

Returning to Firebase Console, Google (alone) is enabled as a sign-in provider & I've got a project support e-mail set up for that sign-in provider, as I'd always previously done.

I did notice the latest version of FirebaseUI required a change to imports:
old code that had:

```
import FirebaseUI
```

now seems to require

```
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
```

(as of Oct, 1, 2021, the documentation for this had not been updated online, but some digging & query via GitHub got me the update info above). Again, with these changes things do compile (although I need to run on my iPhone since M1 Macs can't seem to run FirebaseGoogleAuthUI in the simulator). Yet clickign on "Sign in with Google" crashes with the error:
"OAuth client ID not found. Please make sure Google Sign-In is enabled in the Firebase console. You may have to download a new GoogleService-Info.plist file after enabling Google Sign-In"
I'd never been required to do any additional OAuth work beyond setting up Authentication Sign-In provider for Google in the Firebase Console. Has something changed that I need to also address? Thanks for any help!

Comment: "although I need to run on my iPhone since M1 Macs can't seem to run FirebaseGoogleAuthUI in the simulator"  What does that mean?  Is 'FirebaseGoogleAuthUI' still in use?

Comment: Check `pod outdated` to make sure that all the pods updated successfully. Recent Firebase versions should support the M1.

Answer (score 5):

did you get solutions?
I found following approach, it works for me.

https://issueexplorer.com/issue/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/1003

I think 2 Official Firebase Codes are too old,

OLD #1

```
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
```

OLD #2

```
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
  FUIGoogleAuth(),
  //... I DON'T CHECK FACEBOOK, TWITTER AMD PHONE...//
]
```

Working code (Swift 5) is

UPDATED #1

```
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!
```

UPDATED #2

```
    let googleAuthProvider = FUIGoogleAuth(authUI: authUI)
    let authProviders: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        googleAuthProvider,
        FUIEmailAuth()
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me

1)Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then select the Info tab, and expand the URL Types section.

2)Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.

Comment: based on doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin (Point number 2)